# Read multiple schema sets into a dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I'm trying to generate a DataSet from a XmlSchema I have a another schema defining a simple type i. How can I add multiple schemas into a Dataset

The First Schema would generate the structure of the Dataset and one of the elements in the schema is

```
<xs:element name="CkptID" type="EM_SignedInt" />
```

The type " EM_SignedInt " is mentioned in a different schema

The second Schema defining the simple type is  below

```
<xs:complexType name = "EM_SignedInt">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:int">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="AttG_Property"/>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
```

How do I add the type to the Dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. To resolve this issue, include the schema which defines the simple type in the main schema using xs:include. The important point to note here is that we should not include the "targetNamespace" parameter in the schema which has to be included in any other schema so that it automatically includes the namespace which is defined in the main schema and becomes a part of that schema.

Include the following parameters in the main schema(Main.xsd, in this case):

```
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Main.xsd" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop"  targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Main.xsd"  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="3.0.4 01-07-2011">
```

To include the schema defining the simple type(base.xsd in this case),use:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="base.xsd"/>
```

Now you can add this main schema to load into the dataset which works fine!